# Python - Making text files

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to be having various problems with my code. Firstly I cannot split the text that the user inputs.

E.g. if they type `bob` for their name, `ha8 9qy` for their postcode and `17/03/10` for their date of birth, the program will return `"bobha8 9qy17/03/10"`.

How should I separate the input? Secondly i cannot find the text file I supposedly make. Lastly, is there a way to return the information to the new display window created by Tkinter?

```
import tkinter as kt
name=input("Enter your name")
postcode=input("Enter your postcode")
dob=input("Enter your date of birth")

window=kt.Tk()
window.title("File")
window.geometry("300x150")
def submit():
    pythonfile = open("User details","w")
    pythonfile.write((name))
    pythonfile.write((postcode))
    pythonfile.write((dob))
    pythonfile = open(("User details"),"r")
    print (pythonfile.read())
    pythonfile.close()
Btn = kt.Button(window, text="Submit", command=submit)
Btn.pack()
```

Comment: There's nothing specific to tkinter about writing text files, and nothing specific to text files about tkinter. A good question that centers around code should be include nothing more than the absolute minimum needed to reproduce a specific problem -- meaning if you're having a tkinter problem it should have text-file-writing aspects factored out, and if you're having a text-file-writing problem it should have tkinter aspects factored out.

Comment: See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and more generally, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And one (real) question to a (StackOverflow) question, please.

Comment: Beyond that, getting into answers: (1) If you want to separate strings that you're writing, consider putting newlines between them; `pythonfile.write('\n')` will do that, for instance.

Comment: (2) Right now, you're relying on the garbage collector to detect that your original (writable) file handle is unreferenced and close it before you start reading. That's implementation-defined behavior not guaranteed by the language; explicitly flush or close your file if you want to be sure that the content you're writing will be on-disk before you reopen for read in a way that's portable across Python interpreters.

Comment: if you create tkinter program then use `tkinter.Entry` instead of `input`

Comment: Use `str.split(separator)` to split a string by the. separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `.txt` afther the filename. Also be sure that the file is in the same folder of the `.py` file. Pay attention to caps and spaces.

`pythonfile = open("User details.txt","w")`

If this does'nt work, try adding `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))` afther the import, for me it fixed the problem.

For the "spacing problem" try:

`pythonfile.write(name, '\n', postcode, '\n', dob)`

Also, when you create a alias for Tkinter use tk, and when you open a file try naming it file_it, or f_in, so it's more readable for other people ...
When naming files don't use spaces, it's just going to make everything harder, try naming it like this: `userDetails.txt` or `user_details.txt`